# Binary search that returns bitwise complement of missing index

Tags: javascript, performance, array, binary-search

While re-writing some old JavaScript code to better handle large arrays, I ended up writing my own binary search method.

I found many examples of binary search methods written in JavaScript, but all the examples I found returned -1 whenever the target was not found in the array. What I really wanted was the bitwise complement of the index where the target belonged if it did not exist in the array, like the BinarySearch method on generic lists in .NET.

This is the code I ended up writing, but I'm curious if I've overlooked any potential performance problems or logic errors. To the best of my knowledge, the code works sufficiently as designed (see [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thriggle/5qhw51jo/)). Please help me review this code and verify that it follows common best practices.

**binarySearch Method**

**Inputs**: `target`: the object being sought in the array;
`comparator`: (optional) comparison method

**Returns:** If positive or zero, the index of the item in the array. If negative, the bitwise complement of the item's proper location in the array.

```
Array.prototype.binarySearch = function (target, comparator) {
    var l = 0,
        h = this.length - 1,
        m, comparison;
    while (l <= h) {
        m = (l + h) >> 1;
        comparison = typeof (comparator) == "undefined" ? (this[m] < target ? -1 : (this[m] > target ? 1 : 0)) : comparator(this[m], target);
        if (comparison < 0) {
            l = m + 1;
            continue;
        } else if (comparison > 0) {
            h = m - 1;
            continue;
        } else {
            return m;
        }
    }
    return~l;
};
```

Using the above, I also wrote a binary insert method, which adds an item to the correct location in an array. I'm curious about this also, and whether there's anything I can do to improve its performance or handle any edge case bugs.

**binaryInsert Method**

**Inputs:** `target`: object being inserted; `duplicate`: (optional) whether to add if it already exists in the array (false by default); `comparator`: (optional) comparison method

**Returns:** Index of new item added to array

```
Array.prototype.binaryInsert = function (target, duplicate, comparator) {
    if (typeof (duplicate) == "undefined") duplicate = false;
    var i = this.binarySearch(target, comparator);
    if (i >= 0) {
        if (duplicate) {
            this.splice(i, 0, target);
        }
    } else {
        i = ~i;
        this.splice(i, 0, target);
    }
    return i;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

• First comment is about the way you are adding the functions to the Array prototype : by just adding them this way, you 'pollute' the keys of the array, so anyone doing a for ... in for instance will enumerate also on the added functions.
-->> Use `Object.defineProperty` to have those function non enumerables.
The pattern could look like :

```
(function () {

    var newArrayMethods = {
        //  Returns a shallow copy of this array
        copy: function () {
            return this.slice(0);
        },

        // Returns true if this array contains 'element', returns false otherwise
        contains: function (element) {
            return this.indexOf(element) >= 0 ;
        }            
    }

    // let's install those methods on the prototype
    for (var newMethodName in newArrayMethods) {
        installFunction(newMethodName, newArrayMethods[newMethodName]);
    }

    function installFunction(name, fn) {
        if (Array.prototype[name]) throw ('Array method ' + name + '() already defined.');
        Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, name, {
            value: fn
        });
    }

})();
```

• Second thing is that typeof is slow : you don't want to use it within a loop.
The code below also avoids one branch per loop.

```
function binarySearch (target, comparator) {
    var l = 0,
        h = this.length - 1,
        m = 0, 
        comparison = 0;
   comparator = comparator || compareNumbers ;

    while (l <= h) {
        m = (l + h) >> 1;
        comparison = comparator(this[m], target);
        if (comparison < 0) {
            l = m + 1;
        } else if (comparison > 0) {
            h = m - 1;
        } else {
            return m;
        }
    }
    return~l;
};

function compareNumbers(a,b) { a-=b;  return (a<0) ? -1 : ( a>0 ) ? 1 : 0 ;  } ;
```

• Array.splice is to be avoided if you seek performances : it is slow and creates garbage.
Do the insertion yourself.
I wrote below insertion function moving forward, to avoid cache miss.

You'll notice i changed the insert function signature so it is more alike to the search (target + comparator arguments first).

Also no need to process an argument that defaults to false.

```
function binaryInsert(target, comparator, duplicate) {
    var i = this.binarySearch(target, comparator);
    if (i >= 0 ) {
        if (!duplicate) return i;
    } else {
        i = ~i;
    }
    insertOneAt(this, target, i);
    return i;
};

function insertOneAt(arr, item, index) {
    var tmp1=item, tmp2=item;
    var len = arr.length;
    for (; index<=len; index++) {
       tmp2 = arr[index]
       arr[index]=tmp1;
       tmp1=tmp2;
    } 
}
```

• Detail : change your binaryInsert comment about the return value to something like :

Returns: Index of new item added to array, or of the existing item if  duplicate==false and the item was found.

• You have also some decision/changes to make about the way you handle duplicates in your search.
As of now search returns *any* matching item's index (compare==0), it does not ensure, for instance, that it is the smallest index.
If it's ok just mention it, otherwise you have to change a bit your search.

Since the insert relies on search, your decision on the search will affect insert's semantic as well.

Comment: Thank you for all the great suggestions and analysis! I've incorporated most of your suggestions in the fiddle. One of the things I'm not sure about is the performance of the custom insert function; based on the results of a [quick-and-dirty jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/binsearch-array-manipulation-patterns), it looks like Array.splice is still faster.

Comment: You're welcome ! It seems in deed that custom insert is not as obviously better as i'd thought : only Firefox agrees with me :-) (look again your jsperf). Notice that for the search :  function compareNumbers(a,b) { return a-b; }  will do the job faster.

Comment: Wow, and it's a really significant performance difference in Firefox! I wonder what they're doing differently under the covers. The only reason I didn't adopt your superior compareNumber method is that I want the binarySearch to also handle string comparisons without requiring a custom comparator function; I could probably check the parameter types myself but I figure at that point I'd be trying to out-optimize the browser's JavaScript implementation.

Comment: For the compare you can use function defaultCompare(a,b) { return (a<b) ? -1 : (a>b) ? 1 : 0; }  to avoid typeof and branching

Comment: I think I see... so the advantage of that approach over defining the compare function inline as `comparator = comparator || function(a,b){return (a<b?-1:(a>b?1:0));};` would be that the binarySearch method wouldn't need to define the compare function every time it's called--the code would define it once and the binarySearch method could just reference it. Is that correct?

Comment: To be completely correct, a smart browser might detect the function as 'constant' (=having no closure) : but for browsers not-that-smart or non-jited (iOS) you make it plain obvious. And bonus, it's more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I made several changes to the code based on GameAlchemist's advice and my own observations.

The improvements:

- Avoid calling `Array.prototype` directly, which pollutes the enumerable keys in the array such that `(for i in arr)` loops mistakenly treat the new array methods as array items. Use `Object.defineProperty` instead
- Avoid `typeof(comparator)==="undefined"`, which could be expensive, and pull the comparator check out of the inner while loop so it's only called once per binarySearch
- Remove unnecessary `continue`'s from binarySearch method
- Use `(l+h)>>>1` (unsigned bitwise rightshift) instead of `(l+h)>>1` (plain ol' bitwise rightshift) to avoid problem with large numbers (between 2147483647 and 4294967290) being interpreted as negatives.
- Setting a variable to false if it is undefined is redundant. Remove unnecessary `typeof(boolean)==="undefined"` check from binaryInsert method

Updated Code:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "binarySearch", {
    value: function (target, comparator) {
        var l = 0,
            h = this.length - 1,
            m, comparison;
        comparator = comparator || function (a, b) {
            return (a < b ? -1 : (a > b ? 1 : 0));
        };
        while (l <= h) {
            m = (l + h) >>> 1;
            comparison = comparator(this[m], target);
            if (comparison < 0) {
                l = m + 1;
            } else if (comparison > 0) {
                h = m - 1;
            } else {
                return m;
            }
        }
        return~l;
    }
});

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "binaryInsert", {
    value: function (target, duplicate, comparator) {
        var i = this.binarySearch(target, comparator);
        if (i >= 0) {
            if (!duplicate) {
                return i;
            }
        } else {
            i = ~i;
        }
        this.splice(i, 0, target);
        return i;
    }
});
```

**Note for Old Browsers:** Above code only works in IE9 and up. I've noticed that `Object.defineProperty` works only on DOM elements in Internet Explorer 8, so to work around that I can wrap the above in a try/catch and if it throws an exception just use my old key-polluting method of calling `Array.prototype` directly.

Also note that this code will start to behave incorrectly when the array length exceeds 4294967290. Alas! Such is the price I pay for using the more efficient `(l+h)>>>1` instead of the more reliable `Math.floor((l+h)/2)`